# Manifest.xml URI not registered . android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, uri, android-manifest

I am new to android development after updating android studio to 3.1 this error has started popup, I am getting URI not registered and other attribute not allowed here error msgs. I tried all similar questions but none of them solved the issue

[image]

Comment: This is because your build want successful , after the update !! not only the manifest every where you will see the Color **`Red`**

Comment: Remove the line xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" and reimport.